# Why passing a QStringView by value is faster than a reference-to-const?

Tags: c++, qt

I have found this in [Qt's Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qstringview.html#details):

> QStringViews should be passed by value, not by reference-to-const:

and they give the following example:

```
void myfun1(QStringView sv);        // preferred
void myfun2(const QStringView &sv); // compiles and works, but slower
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Move semantics, maybe?

Comment: Perhaps `QStringView` has only two members (a pointer and a length), so it is faster to put it on stack than put its address to stack, and always having to dereference it.

Comment: Do you pass your *pointers* by const reference, or by value?

Comment: @geza on many platforms it can be passed in registers, and not touch memory *at all*

Comment: @geza, you are right: [QStringView](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstringview.h.html) has only two members, namely `qsizetype m_size` and `const storage_type *m_data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QStringView` is typically used in high-performance code where creating actual `QString` objects would be slow due to the memory allocation involved. I optimized `QStringView` so that it is as performant as handling a `(const QChar*, size_t)` manually. I even went to the length of having member function calls hand off inline to free functions, passing `*this` by value. All this is to avoid forcing `QStringView` objects onto the stack, or, more generally, into memory.

In virtually all C++ compilers, a `QStringView` object is represented as a pair of CPU registers, and many C++ ABIs (sadly, excluding Windows) support passing such types in CPU registers to functions. If you wrote the member function naïvely, with an implicit `this` parameter as the *address* of the object, calling such a function out-of-line would force the compiler to allocate a `QStringView` object on the stack to be able to pass its address as the first argument of the member function.

There's a second argument for pass-by-value: there are less aliasing problems. As a reference type, `QStringView` exhibits that problem anyway, but consider `std::complex`: Take

```
std::complex &operator*=(std::complex &lhs, const std::complex &rhs);
```

(template args omitted for brevity). This can be called like this:

```
std::complex c = 3 + 4i;
c *= c;
```

If you naïvely implement `operator*=` as if it was a mathematical function:

```
auto r = real(), i = imag();
m_real = r * other.real() - i * other.imag();
m_imag = r * other.imag() + i * other.real();
```

you would have clobbered `other.real()` after the first line, thus calculating a wrong result (yes, people *do* write this code in production). Passing the `rhs` by value makes the problem go away.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did some more search on the topic you brought up. [Here](https://www.quora.com/In-C-when-a-temporary-object-is-created-where-is-it-stored/answer/Joe-Zbiciak?ch=10&oid=97196749&share=ad26780d&target_type=answer) there is a more detailed explanation of what you write. And in the [ch7 of the vol. 5](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) of the Agner Fog's books, we learn that 64-bit Win allow only one register for such object, instead of 2 for Linux/BSD/Mac. And the C++ standard says the object must be trivially copyable. I'm glad to know that now :)

Answer (score 3):

They say in the docs that it should be passed by value, because `QStringView` is not a string itself, it is just kind of an interface (well, that's why it is called "view") giving you the read access to the referenced string. Therefore, most likely the size of `QStringView` is similar to the size of a reference. According to QT source code, `QStringView` has just 2 fields:

```
private:
    qsizetype m_size;
    const storage_type *m_data;
```

On my Debian9 x64 machine with gcc 6.3 the size of this class is 8 (pointer) + 4 (integer) = 12 bytes. The reference size in my case is 8 bytes, consequently there is only a small difference in terms of data copy on function call. Just remember, that on different machine references might be implemented in another way and might be larger.

While I agree that this kind of interface should be passed by copy (not const ref), I don't understand why do they claim that passing it by const ref is actually SLOWER (dereferencing the variable twice doesn't really have any observable effect in modern applications). I really would like to see some test supporting that statement.

Comment: It is highly likely that padding makes this type 16-byte. And it *could* be slower, because if the function modifies other `QStringView` objects (or an object with a  type which is allowed to alias, like `char`), then the compiler has to reload data from the reference. And there is a little overhead of the additional indirection as well. But in certain circumstances, it could be faster too (if the reference just passed to another function, for example).

Comment: deeply agree with your last paragraph. It makes no sense whatsoever that they put this recommendation in the doc. It is so marginal compared to all the  stuff that have to be done in a GUI  application.

Comment: "*While I agree that this kind of interface should be passed by copy (not const ref), I don't understand why do they claim that passing it by const ref is actually SLOWER*" => This is because if you pass an object by reference or pointer, the compiler needs to allocate it on the stack, to get a valid address. While if the object is trivially copyable and small (8 bytes on 64-bit Windows, or 16 bytes on 64-bit Linux, BSD, Mac), the object can stay in the CPU registers, which are faster.